# I get/will get a cable in the box

Tags: future-constructions

I'm looking at the website of the new iPhone, I'm not sure if it comes with a cable or not, the site says it does come with a cable, in this case, should I say:

1. Looks like I get a cable in the box
2. Looks like I will get a cable in the box

Thanks!

Comment: Neither.  It is "Looks as though... "

Comment: @Chenmunka Hi, so it's 'Looks as though I get a cable in the box'?